# Get the current function name in the Flask template context

Tags: python, flask

What I basically need is something like the following:

```
{{ url_for(current_view) }}
```

in a Jinja2 template, such that if the response came from:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render('index.html')
```

then `current_view` equals to `"index"`, i.e., the actual view name, such that `url_for` works.

To provide some context, this problem actually came up when using `flask-babel`. I want to have a "switch language button" that basically redirects to the same url, but with a different language code, as in:

```
{{ url_for(current_view, lang_code="es") }}
```

if you are in the English page, and `lang_code="en"` if you are on the Spanish page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `request.endpoint`:

```
{{ url_for(request.endpoint) }}
```